# Problem with catkin_make

Tags: cv-bridge, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had trouble with the cv_bridge. When I try to make my catkin_ws, I get the following error:

`CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake:106 (message): Project 'cv_bridge' specifies '/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev' as an include dir, which is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in '/opt/ros/kinetic//opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.2.0-dev'.  Ask the maintainer 'Vincent Rabaud <vincent.rabaud@gmail.com>' to fix it. Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package) apriltags_ros/apriltags_ros/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)`

When I navigate to /opt/ros/kinetic/include, i find that there is an opencv-3.1.0-dev, but not 3.2. How do I upgrade?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261819/problem-with-catkin_make/) by [yhindy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30404/yhindy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use your system's package manager to update ROS. e.g. For Ubuntu, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/package-management.html).

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2017-05-16**:
Also, if you had a build space, you should delete it as it still refers to OpenCV 3.1 and it got bumped to 3.2. yes, my fault ... The version was so close to 3.2 with the patches that I bumped the version number, which should not release in a ROS release ...

**Comment by [yhindy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30404/yhindy/) on 2017-05-16**:
Thank you Geoff! I got it to work.

**Comment by [balajithevoyager](https://answers.ros.org/users/30029/balajithevoyager/) on 2017-08-11**:
Hi, I am having the same issue, can you please tell step by step how to resolve this issue

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-08-15**:
For how to use the package manager to update your system, see the page linked in the answer. For deleting your build space after doing that update, go to your workspace and delete the `build` directory.

**Comment by [ravit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23198/ravit/) on 2018-03-04**:
I had the same problem and it worked. Thanks!